# Percentage Contribution To Euclidean Distance

Tags: linear-algebra

I am currently working with Euclidean Distances.

I am calculating the distance between two n-dimensional sets of data points, but I really want to know how much each point contributes to the final Euclidean Distance

For example, if we were considering a right triangle, I would want to know what percentage of the length of the hypotenuse came from each leg.

The problem is that I can't seem to find a way to relate the individual points to the amount of distance that they contribute.

Another example:

P1: 1, 2, 3

P2: 0, 0, 0

The total distance would be equal to the square root of 14.....but what percentage of that came from each point?

Is my only option for comparing lengths Squared Euclidean Distance?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The basic idea is flawed.  Let us take your example in 2D of a right triangle, specifically $5,12,13.$  You are asking what part of the $13$ came from the $5$?  If I decrease the short side to zero, the hypotenuse becomes $12$, so it seems only $1$ of the hypotenuse came from $5$.  If I decrease the long side to zero, the hypotenuse becomes $5$, so it seems $8$ came from the long side.  This leaves $4$ of the hypotenuse unaccounted for.

Asking how much of the result comes from each input makes sense if the output is a linear function of the inputs.  If it is almost linear, you won't be far off.  But if it is far from linear, you can't get a reasonable answer.

Answer (score 1):

Suppose the lengths of the two legs are $a$ and $b$ with hypotenuse $c =\sqrt{a^{2} + b^{2}}$. In the limiting case, if $a = 0$ then $100\%$ of $c$ comes from $b$ and $0\%$ from $a$. Similarly if $b = 0$ then $100\%$ of the hypotenuse comes from $a$ and $0\%$ comes from $b$. If $a = b$ then $50\%$ of the hypotenuse comes from each of $a$ and $b$. One function, perhaps the simplest, that satisfies these conditions is the percent from $a$ is $\frac{a}{a + b}$ and the percent from $b$ is $\frac{b}{a + b}$. These functions have the additional properties that if $a$ is held fixed and $b$ increases the percent from $b$ will increase. Similarly if $b$ is fixed and $a$ increases.